# Trial version of Xubuntu keeps running instead of the installed version (on VirtualBox)

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, xubuntu

My laptop has VirtualBox running and a USB external drive attached. I installed Xubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox from a downloaded ISO image, after defining partitions (including root and swap) on the external drive ("Something Else" partitioning option chosen) and placing the bootloader on the external drive as well (/dev/sdb/).

At the end of the install, Xubuntu restarted. But the trial version started instead of the installed version. I restarted Xubuntu several times manually, and the trial version runs, not the installed version. What do I need to do to run the installed version?

Do I need to change the "**Settings** → **Storage** → **Controller IDE**" option in the VirtualBox? Any help would be immensely appreciated! I can provide specifics of my setup if asked. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you have "ejected" the ISO from the Virtualbox virtual CD drive

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do you "eject" the ISO from the Virtualbox virtual CD Drive? If you mean remove the "Optical Drive" entry in "Settings, Storage, Controller IDE", I tried that and I get error message "Fatal error: no bootable medium found! system halted".

Comment: It should just be a matter of selecting `Devices` from the main VirtualBox menu, then `Optical Drives...` `Remove disk from virtual drive`

Comment: When I do remove the disk from virtual drive in VirtualBox, then I hit Start, I get the error message "fatal error: no bootable medium found! system halted".